# Understanding Universal links delegate method and its purpose in iOS

Tags: ios, appdelegate, ios-universal-links

I have currently implemented universal links in my iOS app. I have however a scenario in which it would appear that my apps

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method is called first and then only is the universal links delegate method called

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
```

As such, when opening the app via a universal link and when inspecting `launchOptions[@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey"][@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"]` I see that the app was opened by the link in the `NSUserActivity`. Based on this I have the following questions:

1. Where should my logic sit in handling the link? Should the logic lie in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or the universal link app delegate method? Should I have an if statement in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that follows different logic depending on how the app was launched?
2. What is the order in which is calls the delegate methods? So for example it appears that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called first, is the `continueUserActivity` called only when `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` finished or does it start `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` lets the code run in this method and then also start the code in `continueUserActivity` on a separate thread? I've found that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will run on the main thread but should any code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` run on a concurrent thread i.e `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` makes a service call then the `continueUserActivity` method starts running without `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` having finished. When this happens the theres funny issues that then starts to occur on the main thread. How can `continueUserActivity` only be invoked when `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is done? For this scenario should I be doing some sort of `NSOperation` rather?
3. Should `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` store the result of the link being managed in a cache and then when `continueUserActivity` is called then return the value in that result?

The Apple documentation doesn't really go into the nitty gritty of how the app delegate methods work under that hood. Some help in answering these questions would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I only know, that `continueUserActivity` calls every time. If an application is not launched yet, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` calls first and after that calls `continueUserActivity` method.